why does $|z|=\sqrt{\Re^2(z)+\Im^2(z)}$, which elements to $\mathbb{R}$?
The formula what I think it is $|z|=\sqrt{\Re^2(z)+\Im^2(z)} \in \mathbb{R}$.
why does $|z|=\sqrt{\Re^2(z)+\Im^2(z)} \in \mathbb{R}$ (although $|A|=\sqrt{(A.x)^2+(A.y)^2} \in \mathbb{R}$);
Like to find the modulus of $3+4i$,
$|3+4i|=\sqrt{\Re^2(3+4i)+\Im^2(3+4i)}$
$=\sqrt{3^2+4^2}=\sqrt{25}=5$; Which elements to $\mathbb{R}$.
So I don't understand why $|z|=\sqrt{\Re^2(z)+\Im^2(z)} \in \mathbb{R}$.
[Symbol and notation help]
this notation $\Re^2(z)$ works as same as $\operatorname{Re}(z)^2$. [the symbol $\Re$ represents $\operatorname{Re}$.]
and this notation $\Im^2(z)$ works as same as $\operatorname{Im}(z)^2$. [the symbol $\Im$ represents $\operatorname{Im}$.]
WHY DID THE REPUTATIONS GO DOWN

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Literally definitions. What exactly do you not understand about how they connect?

both of the square roots of a non-negative real number are real. We typically choose the non-negative one from convention. There is no way to interpret e.g. $\sqrt {25}$ as a non-real number

I am not sure what the issue is OP. The real and imaginary parts are both real right? Thus the sum of their squares is a non-negative real number, which has a square root that is also a real number.

@AnCar I speculatively infer that the OP's issue is one of geometric visualization.  This lack of visualization, in this instance has plausibly prevented the OP from developing the necessary intuition.

This is an unusual situation, where the original poster is asking for an intuitive explanation for the formula for $~|z| ~: ~z \in \Bbb{C}.~$ Given this situation, I don't see how that the OP (i.e. original poster) can show work, because (very plausibly) the OP has not been provided with any geometric visualization that would explain the formula.
So, in this situation, I do not regard it as critical that the OP has omitted from the posted question, such details as

their math education
how/where they first encountered the formula for $~|z|,~$
what tools (i.e. previous worked problems, previous examples, or theorems) preceded the formula. 
Here, it stands to reason that if the OP had been supplied (for example) pertinent geometric visualization, then they would not be posting this question.

So, in my judgement, in this unusual situation, the posted question is not low quality with respect to lack of effort shown on the part of the original poster.
Now we come to the interesting issue.  Unquestionably, given the MathSE priority given to maintaining a repository of high-quality questions, this question is low-quality.  That is, the question is so trivial as to not be interesting to mathematicians.
However, there is a general MathSE trend to tolerance for uninteresting questions where the OP has shown effort.  Here, the OP has, in my opinion, as I have explained above, shown what effort that they could.
So, I will answer the question.

Given any complex number $~z,~$ the expression $~|z|~$ is intended to represent the non-negative measure of the distance of the complex number $~z~$ to the origin.  Here, the origin is defined to be the complex number $~\displaystyle 0 + i(0) ~: ~i = \sqrt{-1}.$
Assume that $~x,y \in \Bbb{R},~$ and that $~z = x + iy.$
Then, you have that

Re$(z) = x,~$ and Im$(z) = y.~$

If you let points $~A,B,C,~$ respectively denote the complex numbers $~[ ~0 + i(0) ~], ~[ ~x + i(0) ~], ~$ and $~[ ~x + i(y) ~],~$ then you have that $~\triangle ABC ~$ is a right triangle, with hypotenuse $~\overline{AC},~$ and the (non-negative) length of the hypotenuse corresponds to the distance of point $~C = x + i(y)~$ to the origin.


Therefore, $~|z| = ~$ the (non-negative) distance of point $~C = x + i(y)~$ to the origin.  Letting $~m(\overline{AC})~$ denote the non-negative length of the line segment $~\overline{AC},~$ then you have, by the pythagorean theorem, that
$$[ ~m(\overline{AC}) ~]^2 = [ ~m(\overline{AB}) ~]^2 + [ ~m(\overline{BC} )~]^2 \implies $$
$$|z|^2 = x^2 + y^2 \implies $$
$$|z| = \sqrt{ ~x^2 + y^2 ~} \implies $$
$$|z| = \sqrt{ ~[ ~\text{Re}(z) ~]^2 + [ ~\text{Im}(z) ~]^2 ~}.$$

Oh, I knew the formula $a^2+b^2=c^2$!

@neitherchecker To understand why your posted question was downvoted, you need to re-read the first part of my answer.  While I tried to justify taking the position that your posted question is of high enough quality to deserve an answer, there is no question that my position is controversial.   ...see next comment

@neitherchecker For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.
